# CustomList<T extends A> type mismatch

Tags: java, android, arraylist, extends, type-mismatch

First problem fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239393/use-method-from-t-class-extending-arraylistt) but it came with another one, and I prefered to make a new thread.

I have a `CustomList<T extends A>` which will be used with `Class A1` and `Class A2`, both extending `Class A`.

I have a `Class B` which contains `CustomList`s :

```
public Class B
{
    CustomList<A1> listA1 = new CustomList<A1>();
    public CustomList<A1> getListA1(){ return listA1;}
}
```

Whenever I try to do

```
for(A1 obj : myBClass.getListA1())
{
    /*Do something*/
}
```

I got `Type mismatch : cannot convert from element type A to A1.` I don't get it since `getListA1()` returns a `CustomList<A1>`. I think it may be because of `CustomList<T extends A>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First:

```
class CustomList<T extends A> extends ArrayList<T>
```

Second:

```
class A {
    public boolean getCustomBoolean() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Third:

```
class A1 extends A {
}
```

Result:

```
CustomList<A1> customList = new CustomList<A1>();
customList.add(new A1());

for (A1 obj: customList) {
    System.out.println(obj.getCustomBoolean());
}
```

Prints: true

Comment: It is exactly what I got. I just needed to Clean the project and it works well now.

Comment: Thanks to you for answering both of my questions ;)